# Restricted Lie algebtras and their root system

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking for a **not** technical introduction to the topic of "Restricted Lie algebras". In particular I'd appreciate if you could provide me some explicit examples of root systems for some low rank of the above mentioned type of Lie algebras. I'd like to understand how the notions of Cartan subalgebra, simple roots and maximal torus are modified in this context (if they still make sense).

Many thanks

Comment: The book "Modular Lie algebras and their representations " by Strade and Farnsteiner is very good. For some explicit example, take the root system of the restricted Lie algebra of classical type $A_n$ of rank $n$, so for example $n=1$ or $n=2$.

Comment: Sorry for  my late reply and many thanks for your comment :-)